# Retorna los usuarios que no han cancelado por mes (En un alquiler) Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buen dia chicos, como retorno yo un lista de usuarios que no han cancelado en meses atrás incluyendo el actual ejemplo:
Tengo la tabla llamada **rents** donde se alquila un inmueble esta a su vez relaciona con dicho inmueble bien sea **casa, apartamento, piscina o parqueadero**. Donde también se guarda el usuario que alquila, esta tabla se llama **rents** que a su vez guarda una relación con **rent_payments** (Tabla) esta acá es donde se guardan los pago de dicho alquiler realizado por el usuario; necesito retornar solo el listado de usuarios que tienen deudas pendientes, Tomando en cuenta que no se deben mostrar los usuarios **superadmin, y admin** que son los que controlan el sistema solo debe mostrar **propietarios e inquilinos**

Dejo un ejemplo de la BD y modelos de Laravel

**Tabla users**:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('superadmin','admin','propietario','inquilino','empleado') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `residential_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_verified_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_phone_unique` (`phone`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Tabla rents:**

```
CREATE TABLE `rents` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `valor_garantia` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `valor_alquiler` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `renta` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `alicuota` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `residential_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `house_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `office_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `departament_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_premise_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `living_room_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parking_lot_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `building_detail_floor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `frecuencia_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `month_payment` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Tabla rent_payments:**

```
CREATE TABLE `rent_payments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mont_paymet` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `valor_garantia` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `valor_alquiler` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `renta` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `alicuota` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Quiero devolver un listado de usuarios que no me han cancelado filtrando por mes de la tabla `rent_payments`

Ejemplo :
Filtro del mes de agosto:

usuarios:

1. Eider inquilino, no cancelo
2. Jesuan A. propietario, no cancelo
3. Jesus A. inquilino, no cancelo
4. Jennifer Mogolon inquilino, no cancelo

**Nota: El sistema esta hecho en laravel**

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: No no he intentado realizar las consultas, para ver si alguien me da la idea de como realizar este procedimiento

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: @gbianchi Listo creo que lo resolvi por mi mismo igual gracias por tu comentario

Comment: @vdjkelly agregalo como una respuesta y luego lo marcas como una solución

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero Estoy en eso unos minutos

Answer (score 0):

Un solucion a este problema es devolver los usuarios que no tiene una renta pagada por mes y año.

**Ejemplo de mi consulta con Eloquent**, espero les sea de ayuda

```
$payment = User::whereDoesntHave('rent_payment', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereMonth('month_payment', 9);
            $query->whereYear('created_at', 2019);
        })->with(['rent'])->get();
```